# vite : Невозможно загрузить файл D:\Web App2022\web\node_modules\.bin\vite.ps1

Tags: php, laravel

Использую laravel 9.35.1, composer 2.4.2. После выполнения команды vite, происходит вывод текст след.ошибки:

[image: Текст сообщения об ошибки]

В разных источниках предлагается изменить политику выполнения через Powershell командой Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted, но это приводит к возникновению другой ошибки:

```
PS D:\Web App2022\web> vite
failed to load config from D:\Web App2022\web\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'
Require stack:
- D:\Web App2022\web\node_modules\vite\dist\node-cjs\publicUtils.cjs
- D:\Web App2022\web\node_modules\vite\index.cjs
- D:\Web App2022\web\vite.config.js
- D:\Web App2022\web\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-4da11a5e.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Web App2022\web\node_modules\vite\dist\node-cjs\publicUtils.cjs:5:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Object._require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (file:///D:/Web%20App2022/web/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4da11a5e.js:63540:17)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
```

Comment: `node -v` что показывает?

Comment: @InDevX, v14.17.3

Comment: обновите ноду, у меня то же самое было, до 16 тогда ещё обновился и пропала ошибка

Comment: @InDevX, спасибо большое, также я сменил версию интерпретатора с 7.4 на 8.1. Это привело к тому, что композер автоматически добавил в зависимости vite после создания нового проекта.